# how to know 'Pending Requests' for my facebook app

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbconnect

I have make one facebook app. I have send requests of that facebook app to lots of facebook users, How do I know that how many users has not accepted my facebook app requests.

Answer (score 1):

"How do I know that how many users has not accepted my facebook app requests."

1) You app is told, after a Request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) is made, how many id's (and which ones) the request was sent to. So store the list of ids somewhere in your datastore, removing duplicate ids of course.

```
{
  request: 'REQUEST_OBJECT_ID'
  to:[array of USER_IDs]
}
```

2) When someone comes to your app thru the request, you get their ID.  You are removing the requests per the documentation, correct?

> When a user is directed to your app by clicking accepting a Request
>   you must delete the request after it has been accepted. Requests are
>   not automatically deleted once they have been clicked, thus it is the
>   developer’s responsibility to clear them once they have been accepted.

3) So when you remove the accepted id from your list, you still have a complete list of ids who have not accepted your app.

Happy coding!